# Read WCF REST date from android

Tags: java, android, .net, wcf, datetime

What's the easiest way to read a .NET DateTime sent over a WCF REST service on an android program? The dates are serialized in the following format: Data=/Date(1326273723507+0100)/

Is there an easy way to deserialize this dates?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the deserialize on the .NET Side or on android

Comment: I want to deserialize on android.

Comment: Something similar, hope it helps ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671373/unparseable-date-1302828677828-trying-to-deserialize-with-gson-a-millisecond

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589816/net-json-date-format

Answer (score 8, accepted):

well I had exactly the same problem, I resolved it with that simple code

```
public class Json {

  /**
   * Convertit une date Json en java.util.Date
   * @param jsonDate
   * @return
   */
  public static Date JsonDateToDate(String jsonDate)
  {
    //  "/Date(1321867151710+0100)/"
    int idx1 = jsonDate.indexOf("(");
    int idx2 = jsonDate.indexOf(")") - 5;
    String s = jsonDate.substring(idx1+1, idx2);
    long l = Long.valueOf(s);
    return new Date(l);
  }
}
```

if you use gson, you can also use that solution : [gson serialization of Date field in MS WCF compatible form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874193/gson-serialization-of-date-field-in-ms-wcf-compatible-form)

Answer (score 4):

The XML Serializer serializes Datetime instances using the Ticks property for best precision (the Ticks is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001). It's the number you are seeing here, followed by +0100 which means GMT + 1:00

To translate ticks into a valid java date, see Jon Skeet's (All roads lead to Jon Skeet) answer here:

[C# DateTime.Ticks equivalent in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706306/c-sharp-datetime-ticks-equivalent-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending and receiving dates to/from a WCF REST service. After much mucking around converting from ticks to milliseconds since the Epoch (using Jon Skeet's answer), I decided just to store the dates as the Java long values (from date.getTime()) so that I don't do any conversion to and from the Android device. If I need to see them on the .NET side, then I'll do the conversion. So, if you have control over the WCF end and the database, keep them as longs.